# C++ Pointer to Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Im trying to do a pointer to pointer to a dynamic array that his elements will be a pointer to "figurasGeom"

How can I do it? I started with the pointer to pointer but Im not sure if that is ok..

```
figuraGeom  ** lista;
```

Is there another way to make a dynamic array without using "vector"?

I have something like this but I dont know how to implement it

```
figuraGeom* vectr [];
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Seems like you need vector<figuraGeom*> **lista;

Comment: That's a good start. Now continue. Try to allocate some a "vector" for this. Try to allocate a single item in the vector.

Comment: Thats Ok. But maybe you can implement some kind of data structure,it will be easier to use and debug

Comment: And when you say "pointer to pointer to vector" that doesn't really make much sense. I think it's more likely that you're after a vector of pointer (e.g. `std::vector<figuraGeom*> lista`), which indeed can be implemented using pointers-to-pointers if you're not allowed to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you left the vector part out, so you would need something like this:

```
vector<figuraGeom*> **lista;
```

But this is a really weird data representation, at least in C++. You should start working more with higher-level containers and/or smart pointers in C++.

Comment: Thank you very much but I have one question, How can I make a get set of lista? it will be something like this?

void listaFiguras::setLista(figuraGeom **iLista){lista = iLista;}

I dont understand why I got error here

Comment: No, you should probably use vector<igureGeom*> lista; (or even with a smart pointer) and then just .at() or insert/push_back().

Comment: I can't make a getset?

Comment: You can make an accessor which uses .at() internally as well as mutator, using the aforementioned method. you can also get the whole container by returning it, and so on, but that does not make so much sense, probably.

Comment: My teacher said me that I have to use get set of lista, then I will have to tell him that I can't do it

Comment: You can, but I wonder if you had misunderstood your teacher.

Comment: Create a new class, listaFiguras. Please note, this is NOT heiress figure, or any other. Have the following characteristics: 

Have two attributes: 
numElements: integer. 
list: pointer to pointer to FIG. It will point to a dynamic vector, each element of which is a pointer to FIG. 


Have the following methods: 
Set and get to numElements and ready. 
Constructor with no parameters, it will list numElements NULL and 0. 
vaciarLista, release the memory area pointed to by list. 
Destroyer, which releases the memory area pointed to by list, by calling vaciarLista.

Comment: If your teacher insists that students directly use pointers in this situation, then he either wants you to learn pointers (a debatable goal if the students are newbies) or he doesn't really teach C++ but something which C++ programmers ironically like to call "C with Classes", in which case you should choose a different course if you can :)